# Safari - Web site Crashing in iOS 6.0.1 and not in iOS 5.x

Tags: safari, crash, ipad-3

I'm trying to open the following URL in iPad 3 Safari browser.
http://www.pearsonschool.com/index.cfm?locator=PS1yJe&PMDbProgramId=110081&sampleId=11241

And doing the following steps:

Click on "Explore the innovative technology of Teacher Place for yourself"
On the top left, click on "Dash" -> Teacher Content 
Then select CMP3 Grade 7
Click on Accentuate the Negative
Then click on "3" (Multiplying and Dividing..)
Select "Problem 3.1"
Click "Launch" button

Here we have 3 options to expand viz Launch Video, Connecting to Prior or Knowledge and Presenting the Challenge.
Expand all the 3 items by clicking ">" button on right of these options.
Scroll to the bottom

It crashes.

Its working fine on iOS 5 Safari. But its crashing on iOS 6.0.1 Safari.

The following is the message that I noted during crash:

```
??Jan 31 07:21:13 Happiestminds kernel[0] <Debug>: 008192.238887 wlan.A[568] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::checkRealTimeTraffic():  now 8192.238881625 num entries 4
??Jan 31 07:22:07 Happiestminds ReportCrash[355] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MobileSafari[230]
??Jan 31 07:22:07 Happiestminds ReportCrash[355] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
??Jan 31 07:22:07 Happiestminds com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0x61fb][230]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0x61fb]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
??Jan 31 07:22:07 Happiestminds backboardd[51] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0x61fb]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
??Jan 31 07:22:07 Happiestminds ReportCrash[355] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileSafari_2013-01-31-072206_Happiestminds.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

I couldn't understand why is it crashing in latest safari.... When googled, i found that some URL's saying its problem related to Redirections, some say about bookmarking and some say about memory management. But I couldn't find the exact issue.

Can some one help me in identifying the exact issue please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As and when there's updates in the browsers, we have to change the javascript etc respectively in the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to debug the javascript using chrome on mac, add console.log to your code and follow this tutorial:

http://devcoma.blogspot.it/2014/03/how-to-investigate-ios-safari-crashes.html

I've used a proxy installed on my mac in order to debug and trace from ios safari to the chrome dev tools.

I found that on my web app safari crashed when using iframes, css transitions, css overflow property and, the jQuery ready event, not all at the same time, obviously.